# Custom key for aes/rijndael on vbscript

Tags: java, encryption, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on a JAVA program which makes requests to an asp file and it's working fine.

Now I want to encrypt POST requests, but I need to use the same key for encryption on JAVA and ASP for decrypting correctly (or that's what I think).

How can I generate a key from a String on vbscript?
And do I need to custom the IV? I don't know what is that :(

(I never encrypted anything, I'm new to this)

```
set obj = server.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged")
set utf = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
s="This is a private message"
bytes=utf.GetBytes_4(s)
obj.GenerateKey()   'need to custom this
obj.GenerateIV()    'need to custom this?
set enc=obj.CreateEncryptor()
set dec=obj.CreateDecryptor()

bytec=enc.TransformFinalBlock((bytes),0,lenb(bytes))
sc=utf.GetString((bytec))
response.write sc

byted=dec.TransformFinalBlock((bytec),0,lenb(bytec))
sd=utf.GetString((byted))
response.write sd
```

Comment: I suggest you learn about KDFs or else you're going to make some security mistakes here.

Comment: Why is the server written in Classic ASP VBScript if the client is in Java?

Comment: The accepted answer uses AES in CBC mode (the default `Mode` of `RijndaelManaged`) but it does not perform message authentication code (MAC) verification which is necessary while using AES in CBC mode. MAC prevents an adversary from altering the IV or ciphertext without getting detected. I have written my own solution to perform AES encryption with MAC here: [github.com/susam/aes.vbs](https://github.com/susam/aes.vbs). It works with Base64 encoded keys and takes care of MAC computation/verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days investigating, I'll post what I finally did. I know that isn't a good practice and I'll change it soon, but It's okay for now.

ASP CODE (decrypts java request)

```
response.write desencriptar(encryptedStringHere)

Function desencriptar(str)
  set obj= CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged")
  set utf8 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
  ekey = "16byteskeyhere" 'you'll need to change this 
  eiv = "16bytesIVhere"   'you'll need to change this 
  obj.BlockSize = 128
  obj.Key = utf8.GetBytes_4(ekey)
  obj.IV = utf8.GetBytes_4(eiv)
  obj.Padding = 5
  set decryptor=obj.CreateDecryptor()
  desencriptado = Base64ToByte(str)
  byted=decryptor.TransformFinalBlock((desencriptado),0,lenb(desencriptado))
  desencriptado = utf8.getString((byted))
  desencriptar = desencriptado
end function

Function Base64ToByte(ByVal vCode)
  Dim oXML, oNode
  Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")
  Set oNode = oXML.CreateElement("base64")
  oNode.dataType = "bin.base64"
  oNode.text = vCode
  Base64ToByte = oNode.nodeTypedValue
  Set oNode = Nothing
  Set oXML = Nothing
End Function
```

JAVA CODE (encryption function)

```
public static String aesEncrypt(String value, String key, String initVector) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Rijndael");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> Docs: [RijndaelManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx) | [PaddingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) | [CipherMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode(v=vs.110).aspx)